# keep the returned matrix after indexing as a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I followed a tutorial https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/matrix/ about R language on how to keep the returned matrix after indexing a matrix, instead of a vector. However, it does not work and the class of the returned matrix is still a vector

I tried to use one comma, then two comma like it was shown in the tutorial.

```
[1] 3 6 9
> class(x[x%%3==0])
[1] "integer"
> x[x%%3==0, drop=FALSE]
[1] 3 6 9
> class(x[x%%3==0, drop=FALSE])
[1] "integer"
> x[x%%3==0,, drop=FALSE]
Error in x[x%%3 == 0, , drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
> x[x%%3==0,,.drop=FALSE]
Error in x[x%%3 == 0, , .drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
> x[x%%3==0,,drop=FALSE]
Error in x[x%%3 == 0, , drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
> class(x[x%%3==0, drop=FALSE])
[1] "integer"
```

The class is still integer, instead of matrix, which is what the drop=FALSE is suppose to do

Comment: Note that when you do `x %%3 == 0` on a matrix/data/frame, the output is logical matrix.  You are passingthat as row index

Comment: Do you need `x[rowSums(x%%3==0) == 3, , drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of

```
x %% 3==0
#     A     B     C
#X FALSE FALSE FALSE
#Y FALSE FALSE FALSE
#Z  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

is a logical matrix

Subsetting the initial matrix using logical matrix gives the elements based on the position of `TRUE`

```
which(x%%3 == 0)
#[1] 3 6 9
```

Those are the same values in the `matrix` we got from extraction and this doesn't differentiate any rows, e.g.

```
x > 3
#     A    B    C
#X FALSE TRUE TRUE
#Y FALSE TRUE TRUE
#Z FALSE TRUE TRUE

x[x > 3]
#[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

In order to extract the row as such, we may need to get a logical vector.  One option is `rowSums` and compare with the number of columns

```
x[rowSums(x %%3 == 0) == ncol(x),, drop = FALSE]
#  A B C
#Z 3 6 9
```

#### data

```
x <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A","B","C")))
```

Comment: But what should we do when the matrix is set to byrow=TRUE? I tried it when I set the matrix to byrow=TRUE and all of the combination between rowSums, colSums, and nrow, ncol won't work.

Comment: @user39178  Not sure what you meant.

Comment: It is like this                                                                                                      ```> x <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A","B","C")))
> x[rowSums(x%%3==0)==ncol(x),,drop=FALSE]
     A B C
> x[colSums(x%%3==0)==ncol(x),,drop=FALSE]
  A B C
Z 7 8 9
> x[rowSums(x%%3==0)==nrow(x),,drop=FALSE]
     A B C
> x[colSums(x%%3==0)==nrow(x),,drop=FALSE]
  A B C
Z 7 8 9```

Comment: @user39178  You can check the ouptut of `x%%3 == 0` there is only a single column there 'C'.  In that case, I don't know what your criteria of subsetting.  If it is to subset the 'C' column, `x[, colSums(x%%3 == 0)== ncol(x), drop = FALSE]`

Comment: when I do that, the output is still a row of 3 6 9

Comment: @user39178  For me, it is a getting a matrix with single column